# Why in this sentence the writer wrote the subject before verb to is after why

Tags: grammar

From *Alice in Wonderland*:

> You promised to tell me your history, you know,' said Alice, 'and **why it is** you hate - C and D,' she added in a whisper, half afraid that it would be offended again.

I noticed that the writer wrote “why it is” instead of “why is it”? Isn't that a question?

Answer (score 2):

The word order changes since it is a kind of indirect question.

> Why **is it** that you hate politics? (*direct question*)
> Tell me why **it is** that you hate politics? (*indirect question*)

Answer (score 0):

(note C and D means cats and dogs, Alice is talking to a mouse, who is scared at the word "cat" and so she is using a euphemism)

Alice isn't asking a question.

> "Why is it you hate C and D?  This is question

> "why is it you hate C and D" This is not a question

It is a noun phrase that means "The reason for you hating C and D"

So the mouse promised to tell Alice two things, its history (ie the tale of its life) and the reason it hates cats and dogs."

```
         It turns
          out that
           this 
           mouse
           has a
           very
          long
           tail
            !!
             !
```

Compare this to

> What is it?  (question)

> I will tell you what it is.  (noun phrase)

Comment: There's something wrong about your answer, I can feel it. Please check.